# Propagating Standard Errors

Tags: math, statistics

Say I have an instrument which measures azimuths. I collect a set of measurements and compute a mean, the difference between the mean and the baseline is used as a correction constant on other locations.

Firstly should the standard error of the first set of readings in the baseline be taking into account at other locations with its own standard error? I assume it would propagate into it.

Secondly if so do you just add them together to get the combined StdErr? i.e. Location 1 StdErr + Location 2, StdErr Location 1 StdErr + Location 3 StdErr.

Comment: There are rules for combining measurement errors, which I think a web search will find. However, the very important limitation on those rules is that they are derived assuming that the function which is combining them together is linear, and otherwise a linear approximation has to be made (e.g. by looking at derivatives). Whether that's applicable to your problem can only be determined by looking at whether a linear approximation is accurate enough. I don't know for sure without looking whether or not that's the case, but calculations involving azimuths might be strongly nonlinear.